# Installing Laravel 5.1 application to server with older PHP version

Tags: php, laravel, server, composer-php, version

I created a webapplication using Laravel 5.1 and **PHP v. 5.6**. However, I need to clone this into a CentOS server which has **PHP v. 5.4.16** installed.

Whenever I run composer install, I get the following error:

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in
>   composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to
>   update them. Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable
>   set of packages.

Followed by packages that require PHP >= 5.5.9.

Is there a workaround to make this application work without updating PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No that won´t be possible. The easiest would be to just update your PHP on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install Laravel 5.1 on a server running PHP 5.4. You really have 2 options:

- Try upgrading PHP
- Migrate your application to Laravel 5.0

Migrating should not be that much work, especially if you have tests setup for your application. There will be some features in your 5.1 app that you may lose and have to work around to migrate to 5.0, but overall, it shouldn't be too difficult.